# MYSQL, Python. Tree structure of dependencies between tables in database

Tags: python, mysql

I am concerned about getting dependency structure/graph of my database. This structure is based on foreign keys between tables.

Example.
Let's say, I have a table 'X' (initiate state).There exists finitely many tables Y1,Y2,...,YN which all have a reference to table X by foreign key. And then there are also tables Z1,Z2,...,ZM referencing to tables X,Y1,...,YN.
I wanna get a structure/graph of all tables which are referencing to table X. Either directly or through the 'layers'. E.g. Table Z5 is referencing to table Y5, which has a reference to table X.

This structure should be(imo) ordered, which means that I could simulate 'delete on cascade' behaviour by traversing this structure.

Have u any idea how to achieve this by MYSQL or Python ? Any hints ?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: I am using datajoint framework that has the function you are seeking.

Comment: @MikhailGenkin I'm sorry. Can you be more specific please ? 
I quickly went through the documentation, but I found only function that plot my 'desired' output. I need informations stored in data structure(dict). It was meant as graph in mathematical sense. What is the name of function please ?

Comment: please see https://docs.datajoint.io/python/definition/11-ERD.html. I am not sure that this is what you need. Please note that to use it you will need to invest significant portion of your time to set everything up